# Android System WebView crash in my android app

Tags: android, android-webview

I am developing android epub reader app.

My "book" is a ViewPager (with offscreenPageLimit=1)

Every my page is  a webview
To create each page i load current html (chapter), paginate it by css column feature and scroll the webview to required offset. (Of course, css column feature allows not to use ViewPager and to scroll the single webview for each chapter, and perhaps i'll do it. But may be current approach with separate pages will alow to form book pages more intellectually then css column does..)

To avoid loading html for each page i create 4 webviews (or less for chapters with page ammount <4) and reuse them for all pages in the chapter. To get required page i take layout from destroyed viewpager item to use it in new item and scroll it's webview to required offset.

To avoid user long waiting and scrolling delays i prepare all webviews in foreground service,  and open book for reading as soon as possible (not waiting the end of all chapter processing)

**My problem is a crash of Android system webview.** 
It happens when i attempt to do any action with my app after a big amount of webwiew objects are created and loaded (but i don't see memory problems in my app)
It not happens with small book (when webview count is less then in big books).

But the most interesting thing is that the **crash takes place with  WebView:48.0.2564.106.** 
I am not sure about all previous versions, but **if i roll back  Android system webview app updates (by my device settings menu)  my app is never crashed on this device!!.** And my app never crash in android <= 4.4.* (where android system webview app is not available as google market says)

What is the way to avoid such crash?

And anyway i am a USER of Android System WebView application. Where is the right place i should write to in such case and what diagnostic material i should send?

And it's my log:

```
03-19 21:23:29.965 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD 

MICRODUMP-----
03-19 21:23:29.965 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: V WebView:48.0.2564.106
03-19 21:23:29.968 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: O A arm64 04 aarch64 asus/WW_Phone/ASUS_Z00E_2:5.0.2/LRX22G/12.8.5.222-20151225:user/release-keys
03-19 21:23:29.968 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: G OpenGL ES 3.0 V@100.0 AU@05.00.02.032.013 (GIT@)|Qualcomm|Adreno (TM) 306

------some   large dump body......

03-19 21:23:30.019 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 000000558A0A6000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 1DFAE5DB08164A9177B5EF00DBA461FB0 app_process64
03-19 21:23:30.019 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F69BCF000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 87BAA15A87EF3214FB842CDBFCBC07BD0 libqti-perfd-client.so
03-19 21:23:30.019 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F933A8000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 9E3F0669968C4F39885535CB8DAF94340 libjhead_jni.so
03-19 21:23:30.020 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F93625000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 7E0D6677111122C42F23CCF197EA7A280 libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
03-19 21:23:30.020 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F94444000 0000000000000000 0000000000B62000 E56EB4A5B5AB26743CA568B4762468D10 libsc-a3xx.so
03-19 21:23:30.020 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F94FCA000 0000000000000000 000000000001C000 7600D8B35D7631F30C2DC3DF4A8DD68B0 eglsubAndroid.so
03-19 21:23:30.020 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F95446000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 A45E1DEBA31549A7F266B3A31D8295B10 libqdMetaData.so
03-19 21:23:30.020 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F95458000 0000000000000000 000000000001C000 3477448E74936925018D1A2EBD87ED970 libqservice.so
03-19 21:23:30.020 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F95474000 0000000000000000 000000000001D000 0BDC34532775F02DC1CBE0173993C1BE0 libqdutils.so
03-19 21:23:30.020 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F96DF6000 0000000000000000 0000000002E46000 935201FBA015E7713749F1BE34FEF8BE0 libwebviewchromium.so
03-19 21:23:30.020 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9D1F6000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 C997D119806AABADE6B3248BCB2EDEA00 libwebviewchromium_loader.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9D209000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 A17923E28194CCACBCB1A802F16B19BD0 libjnigraphics.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9D21B000 0000000000000000 000000000001C000 FF498DBEBE045101677AD3F810D7EC4C0 libcompiler_rt.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9D237000 0000000000000000 0000000000027000 7F48A9DC6FF321F4CD8C3157FE291EF40 libandroid.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9D25E000 0000000000000000 0000000000246000 4165BBD45E0105C6A891B7387AF4F5320 libGLESv2_adreno.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9D4A6000 0000000000000000 0000000000067000 6BA3D4CF767CFFD5C4FDE9FE113ACADA0 libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9D50E000 0000000000000000 0000000000050000 C3F365D34D37F07A3BB3AC14CB3966090 libgsl.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9D55F000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 47464101CB75AB44F0C254E6BDB0D9A00 libadreno_utils.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9D576000 0000000000000000 000000000003F000 50BFD84EF0BFFA6F6A54B5DE8AD1C82C0 libEGL_adreno.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E2EC000 0000000000000000 000000000003A000 FCA9B9FCDFED531E41E8ECCDCC002E1E0 libjavacrypto.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E326000 0000000000000000 000000000001E000 B2B9D1A4477DF972B60C7EDE1FC862910 librs_jni.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E344000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 A610DB576720539107D952F91CF10B410 libaudioeffect_jni.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E35C000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 0635263A1CE792C4FF7A4863716305160 libsoundpool.so
03-19 21:23:30.021 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E370000 0000000000000000 0000000000021000 D83FE18F9D71FC4905DEAAC2A095EA3C0 libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E391000 0000000000000000 000000000002D000 F7BB62820A4E5D8642367D091F89C7340 libvorbisidec.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E3BE000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 C30DC5624E4982A947348ACACA53979A0 libstagefright_yuv.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E3D3000 0000000000000000 000000000003B000 CFA9BAD6D3CB6CB0B77E3092D60F80BB0 libstagefright_omx.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E40E000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 9083F46AF4A54271C0883F015A5763EF0 libstagefright_enc_common.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E420000 0000000000000000 000000000001B000 159D899A5B980CA26061F246AA6152E70 libstagefright_avc_common.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E43B000 0000000000000000 000000000005A000 FE1643C507024FCF9577E84D5BF61B860 libopus.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E495000 0000000000000000 0000000000038000 9F9CD6135A362F86EEBED00AF041CAA10 libdrmframework.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E4CE000 0000000000000000 00000000001C9000 BE7EED0EB8511B2B9F09CAFE63E856980 libstagefright.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E697000 0000000000000000 0000000000031000 DD097C389AEE2D7359C4A1C495792B740 libmtp.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E6C8000 0000000000000000 000000000001F000 BD95DE1FB51E9DCBF27CD5697DA9AFC20 libjhead.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E6E9000 0000000000000000 0000000000051000 984991C7E5FCB223E62604D7A8229AA70 libexif.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E73B000 0000000000000000 0000000000073000 BC8F736F3E01FBCD340AD50C516631D70 libmedia_jni.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1054000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 EE5B7EEA4F01318D1232EE8C07922F8A0 memtrack.msm8916.so
03-19 21:23:30.022 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1078000 0000000000000000 0000000000019000 9770F07BAAFEE97321BED22C6EB860B90 libmemalloc.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2794000 0000000000000000 0000000000071000 858468C742C82B571648F6779C54680C0 libjavacore.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA52E0000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 5DE78D074F8BB78CDCA1E563E3FFFE790 gralloc.msm8916.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA5D15000 0000000000000000 000000000001B000 685F6464C005D159D5F32C5BF0AD11AE0 libbacktrace_libc++.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA5D31000 0000000000000000 0000000000485000 597DA3F75A4004EB4E8D1060BA7DD8B30 libart.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA61DC000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 5F76D67DE14FF4A3D3541B9339315CA60 libusbhost.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA61F1000 0000000000000000 000000000006C000 26CB90D6E6738B2ED8689EB9556C70320 libssl.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA625E000 0000000000000000 0000000000168000 9FCCB2691DECB3B1425DC9F55A0205570 libsqlite.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA63C7000 0000000000000000 0000000000022000 3A4A8F11858D7CFB059CC5A1D76566670 libsoundtrigger.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA63E9000 0000000000000000 000000000002B000 3380F3A48B6D8E1B9D24A1B6C53041CE0 libpcre.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6414000 0000000000000000 0000000000026000 231681929FE734B691B58BD01542AFB40 libselinux.so
03-19 21:23:30.025 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA643B000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 11B797252B4CA0FE9645EE7FAD3FD2050 libprocessgroup.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA644E000 0000000000000000 00000000004A9000 4AB90DE09FDA268BB3CBE27DBA1A3E080 libpdfium.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6909000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 89858D4948ED8DC2D4229419BB25AE830 libnetd_client.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA691C000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 3F1CEB2E3B6E07F4DA43D04D1B095DD10 libnativehelper.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6934000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 216E2568F9798BB7291CCDEEBBDBB2B20 libnativebridge.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6947000 0000000000000000 0000000000023000 291A5C4E0459B22E262B414C29EE39910 libminikin.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA696A000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 0AC695DA933E8027A59AD5BCA1C8468D0 libmemtrack.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA697D000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 82870859E4754C2407C0E31AF85CC99D0 libpowermanager.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6993000 0000000000000000 000000000002F000 487AC635B1606EDE59BB8ECC6C34D7BE0 libstagefright_foundation.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA69C2000 0000000000000000 0000000000069000 04ED65E22F776D233E33638406BAC78A0 libsonivox.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6A2D000 0000000000000000 0000000000024000 1593D8599FB4A2BF5C6596E645931E6E0 libcommon_time_client.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6A51000 0000000000000000 000000000001D000 6C9EAAF667C4BCCD8037153A0944482B0 libnbaio.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6A6E000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 AD53796582B4B03D5C9EAA709B5E23E00 libaudioparameter.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6A83000 0000000000000000 00000000000F3000 036130CDD700292FD82296CF634125AD0 libmedia.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6B76000 0000000000000000 0000000000066000 6DCFE450CF7A0851C65697D578D3C3A50 libinputflinger.so
03-19 21:23:30.026 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6BDC000 0000000000000000 000000000003B000 1D3B388ACCF72474511BFB171540C6B20 libinput.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6C17000 0000000000000000 0000000000025000 7A87F694DDAA3F1EA36DCB0B397B31000 libimg_utils.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6C3C000 0000000000000000 0000000000043000 319CC208B2551D9DAB6BE9A6F0765BB60 libjpeg.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA6C80000 0000000000000000 000000000045C000 393CF0152B7F5FE4AEE3DA332FE7B53C0 libskia.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA70E6000 0000000000000000 0000000000037000 0869CFBBB07AFBB7E6733A3C409BF80C0 libRScpp.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA711D000 0000000000000000 0000000000044000 AB45C9855602DC424DBD3FA0B1F9E5810 libpng.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA7161000 0000000000000000 000000000007B000 7F9BF442B0401731AA0792D7929EFA930 libft2.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA71DC000 0000000000000000 000000000005A000 0269DE719AEC7E912F06D53D9F5DA4820 libbcinfo.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA7236000 0000000000000000 0000000000040000 44863268CDD0680E8E8C3CC123782E9E0 libbcc.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA72A6000 0000000000000000 0000000000114000 B2A5A28BDA44845C0C1F86E28E79A0AE0 libc++.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA7427000 0000000000000000 0000000000E18000 F6C3E9A547FFE44A45F13E4327DFE4160 libLLVM.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA824D000 0000000000000000 0000000000060000 BD3E4943830C494712D9984B66DA43440 libRS.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA82AD000 0000000000000000 000000000009F000 AF85A96414DF8F62B5318C11D97267140 libhwui.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA834C000 0000000000000000 00000000001A0000 4464FCC418EAC5930853EF02B2BA23180 libicuuc.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA84F0000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 04EAB0D7C7D592F7711974C1CE95FF200 libgabi++.so
03-19 21:23:30.027 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8508000 0000000000000000 0000000000227000 E2C83704C13D5608DE65AA586CF0913C0 libicui18n.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA872F000 0000000000000000 000000000005F000 4606B66B8E5FBCE6AE129B3783B671860 libharfbuzz_ng.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA878E000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 DB05321689E9DE93C22992D68B21C11D0 libwpa_client.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA87A3000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 6F56E82AA4FA2732CC4DE4F0B379A6BF0 libnetutils.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA87BB000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 A65D8A977B10CBDB8613A30F25BEF7A10 libhardware_legacy.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA87D5000 0000000000000000 0000000000034000 3AAA713DFAAC0545544482D71A776B6E0 libexpat.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8809000 0000000000000000 0000000000196000 9D73793D154F11DB7E1AE67384F0934E0 libcrypto.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA89A1000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 1EAF131A4FD59D1F66AFBEFB029AEDD80 libhardware.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA89B4000 0000000000000000 0000000000022000 7B03D98AA51CF0EBAFEF85FEBCE7B7E90 libui.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA89D6000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 B21C35BB2A82038E2A2322C2603336920 libsync.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA89E8000 0000000000000000 0000000000086000 424D808949B030122CE755E632F2802B0 libgui.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8A6E000 0000000000000000 0000000000019000 858E4203ABA352F2A4C9521B0D83D0A00 libcamera_metadata.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8A87000 0000000000000000 0000000000063000 21CBF7EFC5D1078766C3945311F8EE4E0 libcamera_client.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8AEA000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 9DDDFBB0F9782EC7AC90B2BFF52515950 libspeexresampler.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8AFE000 0000000000000000 0000000000019000 E603F2F72B4B68CF1CDFD2CF8C1736EA0 libaudioutils.so
03-19 21:23:30.028 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8B17000 0000000000000000 000000000002C000 77AB38A6C2609C5124B622F966FE7F1B0 libz.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8B43000 0000000000000000 0000000000056000 0166EA52526B0C62C91072A35D2C36E60 libbinder.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8B99000 0000000000000000 000000000004C000 DAD8CB4CDA79A0D3F67A9F00DE358D620 libandroidfw.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8BE5000 0000000000000000 0000000000020000 F1BCE07D17EDC8A2739C3BE36242A4940 libGLESv2.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8C05000 0000000000000000 000000000001A000 5A788E6D3C5DAAC1332A45CF726AF9BB0 libGLESv1_CM.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8C1F000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 0E74EB601416B18784F157859CB3623D0 libETC1.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8C33000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 4D6517856A57F654A621A2181339EFB70 libunwind-ptrace.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8C46000 0000000000000000 0000000000027000 F1F520632586F2545AA9216C027F0B3D0 libunwind.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8CD6000 0000000000000000 000000000001F000 E1A5ABF9BD80D7190C0DF8E745B00AE90 libgccdemangle.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8CF5000 0000000000000000 000000000001C000 A52AA21F8AE2E863B8ED2B25C92B57AC0 libbacktrace.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8D11000 0000000000000000 0000000000033000 CCF36A87794A0A9AAC78AE406EDA68BC0 libutils.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8D44000 0000000000000000 000000000007F000 B9A1D0E53C6E520AAC8840CBB17B313E0 libstlport.so
03-19 21:23:30.029 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8DC3000 0000000000000000 0000000000024000 75799A105209A71AE5D1543CC765BBF20 libcutils.so
03-19 21:23:30.032 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8DE7000 0000000000000000 00000000000E6000 3F490362049E0DD63D6C5A32536644490 libGLES_trace.so
03-19 21:23:30.032 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8ECD000 0000000000000000 00000000000E3000 F4D1041A6DB0C85ED745BA48DCA1F00E0 libEGL.so
03-19 21:23:30.032 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA8FB6000 0000000000000000 0000000000196000 C4E15E0C2F8E7B40E54CD915AC4B4B8A0 libandroid_runtime.so
03-19 21:23:30.033 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA914D000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 97015F15F26E5BF9176BDEF1C28C39BC0 libstdc++.so
03-19 21:23:30.034 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA9161000 0000000000000000 000000000003C000 76A75B2C3CF37F88B5DAB243AFFA0F2D0 libm.so
03-19 21:23:30.034 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA919D000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 5DBFAD5F95B733D7A7F1691D94BE14E10 liblog.so
03-19 21:23:30.034 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA91B5000 0000000000000000 000000000009D000 61A22245E9C41FE39D4C3A762DBE017B0 libc.so
03-19 21:23:30.035 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA925F000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 E01D8AE3BBB703302376B2A97064C7A40 libsigchain.so
03-19 21:23:30.035 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA9272000 0000000000000000 0000000000011000 013259C140242266A052016B5FF6EFE90 linker64
03-19 21:23:30.036 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: M 0000007FA9290000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 672B2CD6CF8AF6C43BD70F2AB02B3D0C0 linux-gate.so
03-19 21:23:30.036 6716-6716/? A/google-breakpad: -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
03-19 21:23:30.082 3309-3309/ru.bookscriptor W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
03-19 21:23:30.082 3309-3309/ru.bookscriptor W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
03-19 21:23:30.082 3309-3309/ru.bookscriptor W/google-breakpad: 0.83
03-19 21:23:30.082 3309-3309/ru.bookscriptor W/google-breakpad: 5
03-19 21:23:30.082 3309-3309/ru.bookscriptor W/google-breakpad: 2b36f3b4-5935-4081-9d2c-13408ae8c613
03-19 21:23:30.082 3309-3309/ru.bookscriptor W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
03-19 21:23:30.185 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-19 21:23:30.185 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'asus/WW_Phone/ASUS_Z00E_2:5.0.2/LRX22G/12.8.5.222-20151225:user/release-keys'
03-19 21:23:30.186 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
03-19 21:23:30.186 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
03-19 21:23:30.187 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG: pid: 3309, tid: 3309, name: ru.bookscriptor  >>> ru.bookscriptor <<<
03-19 21:23:30.187 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
03-19 21:23:30.221 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG: Abort message: 'FORTIFY_SOURCE: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE. Calling abort().'
03-19 21:23:30.222 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000ced  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000007fa9294150
03-19 21:23:30.222 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     x4   0000007fa9294150  x5   0000000000000005  x6   0000000000000001  x7   0000000000000020
03-19 21:23:30.222 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   ff2d282773716e61  x10  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f  x11  0000000000000001
03-19 21:23:30.222 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000001  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  003551925e745948
03-19 21:23:30.222 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     x16  0000007fe4d230cd  x17  0000000000000001  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000007fa9294150
03-19 21:23:30.222 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     x20  0000007fa9294410  x21  0000007fa9254000  x22  0000000000000002  x23  0000000000000006
03-19 21:23:30.222 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000002  x25  0000007fe4d2363c  x26  0000000000000134  x27  0000000000000000
03-19 21:23:30.222 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000140  x29  0000007fe4d233c0  x30  0000007fa91ce8bc
03-19 21:23:30.222 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     sp   0000007fe4d233c0  pc   0000007fa9213278  pstate 0000000060000000
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000005e278  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000000198b8  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+160)
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000001ae18  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000001467c  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000016ca8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_fatal+128)
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0000000000016ccc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__fortify_chk_fail+32)
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000000000065914  /system/lib64/libc.so (__FD_SET_chk+32)
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0000000000000df4  /system/vendor/lib64/libqti-perfd-client.so (mpctl_send+1028)
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000000000011a1cc  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
03-19 21:23:30.223 16159-16159/? I/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000001ae8050  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat
03-19 21:23:30.742 882-1082/? D/WifiWatchdogStateMachine: CurrentRSSI:-38
03-19 21:23:30.743 882-1064/? E/WifiStateMachine:  ConnectedState !RSSI_PKTCNT_FETCH uid=1000 0 0 "beeline-routerA42A32" fc:75:16:a4:2a:32 rssi=-38 f=2412 sc=60 link=54 tx=0,1, 0,0, 0,0  rx=0,0 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:1049] from screen [on:0 period:-1877069897] gl rssi=-38 ag=0 hr ls-=0 [56,56,56,56,61] brc=0 lrc=0
03-19 21:23:30.743 882-1064/? E/WifiStateMachine:  L2ConnectedState !RSSI_PKTCNT_FETCH uid=1000 0 0 "beeline-routerA42A32" fc:75:16:a4:2a:32 rssi=-38 f=2412 sc=60 link=54 tx=0,1, 0,0, 0,0  rx=0,0 bcn=0 [on:0 tx:0 rx:0 period:0] from screen [on:0 period:-1877069897] gl rssi=-38 ag=0 hr ls-=0 [56,56,56,56,61] brc=0 lrc=0
03-19 21:23:30.744 16207-16207/? I/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'SIGNAL_POLL'
03-19 21:23:30.757 16207-16207/? I/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: Control interface command 'PKTCNT_POLL'
03-19 21:23:30.758 882-1082/? D/WifiWatchdogStateMachine: RSSI current: 4 new: -39, 4
03-19 21:23:30.769 882-1082/? D/WifiWatchdogStateMachine: Fetch RSSI succeed, rssi=-39 mrssi=-38 txbad=0 txgood=33158
03-19 21:23:31.605 882-6741/? W/ActivityManager: Process ru.bookscriptor has crashed too many times: killing!
03-19 21:23:31.605 882-6741/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity ru.bookscriptor/.activities.ReaderActivity
03-19 21:23:31.608 882-909/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-19 21:23:31.610 882-3604/? E/SharedPreferencesImpl: Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/log_files.xml
03-19 21:23:31.673 882-6741/? D/WindowManager: adjustConfigurationLw, config:{0 1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?locale ?layoutDir sw360dp w360dp h615dp 320dpi nrml long port ?uimode ?night finger -keyb/v/h -nav/v} mLidState:1 mHasDockFeature:false mHasKeyboardFeature:false mHasHallSensorFeature:true config.hardKeyboardHidden:2
03-19 21:23:31.681 882-6741/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity ru.bookscriptor/.activities.TotalActivity
```

Comment: Hi? Could you find any solution?